# Save data in a model from a different view

Tags: yii, view, model, save

I have two tables, `business` and `review business`, in `review business` I have `user_id`, `business_id`,`rating` and `review` field. I want to write a review, for that purpose, I need `rating` and `review` fields from the `review business` table, and I want to show them in a view of `business` which I called (`user_business.php`). I successfully bring the `rating` and `review` field from the `review_business` table, and user is able to give his review, but the thing is the data is not saving in the `review business` model. I am posting my code, please find the error.

This is my business controller.

```
<?php

class BusinessController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
                    'rights',
        );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
            public function actionUserbusiness($id)   // this is userbusiness
    {
                    //render main layout
                    $this->layout='main';
                    $model2 = new ReviewBusiness();      getting fields of review business
        $this->render('userbusiness',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
                        'reviewmodel'=>$model2
        ));

    }

    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Business;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Business']))
        {
                     $rnd = rand(0, 9999);  // generate random number between 0-9999

            $model->attributes = $_POST['Business'];

            $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
            $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number + file name
 $model->image = $fileName;
            if ($model->save()) {
                $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../img/' . $fileName);
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
            }
        }

        $this->render('create', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Business']))
        {
            //$model->attributes=$_POST['Business'];
                        $_POST['Business']['image'] = $model->image;
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Business'];
   $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

            if($model->save())
                        {    if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
                {
                    $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../img/'.$model->image);
                }
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                        }
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Business');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Business('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Business']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Business'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Business the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Business::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Business $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='business-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

Now view of userbusiness is given below. Oh and I am using dzraty extension for rating.

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'review-business-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>
    <?php 
    $this->widget('ext.DzRaty.DzRaty', array( 
    'model' => $reviewmodel,
    'attribute' => 'rating',

)); ?>


</ul>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Review Text</label>
<?php echo $form->textarea($reviewmodel,'review',array('maxlength'=>500)); ?>

</div>
 <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: are the two tables connected with foreign key ?

Comment: yes, they are connected

Comment: business_id is a foreign key in review_business table.

Comment: I am unable to find the solution, everytime i google, links of "saving data in to two different model from a single view" opens.

Comment: try to create a debugging method that insert review into db, just to check whether the problem is from view or the model..

Comment: The code seems okej for me!

Comment: I used inspect element-> network, the data is going ,but it is not saving.

Comment: what logic you using to save data into review business table? please post the code, also check is there any validation error while saving the model.

Comment: Well i did this through, by making a form in my veiw, and then in my business controller i handle it and save it.